# eSendex SMS API

Tags: http, forms, post, vbscript, sms

i'm trying to setup a script using classic .asp/vbscript to send an SMS using the eSendex "HTTP Form Post" service.

So far the script is working... here's what it does

1. Takes the form field values for the calling page
2. Sends an email
3. Saves the values into my database

The final thing that I want the script to do is send an SMS by communicating with the eSendex "HTTP Form Post" service, but [their API documentation](https://www.esendex.com/secure/messenger/formpost/SendSMS.aspx) is not very helpful. An example script would have been nice!

If anyone has any experience with eSendex, maybe you could advises me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take to communicate with the Esendex Form Post API from ASP.

You can either form an HTTP POST Request yourself and try POSTing the data directly to it, or you could use the EsendexSdk2.dll they provide as part of the ASP SMS SDK: http://www.esendex.co.uk/Developers/Downloads/ASP-SMS-SDK-Download

You can see examples of how to use the EsendexSdk2.dll with ASP here: http://www.esendex.co.uk/Developers/SDKs/ASP-SMS-SDK

In that zip download you'll find a SendMessage.asp example which takes values from fields on a form and calls SendMessage on the SendService.

The alternative HTTP POST Request approach would require you to do something like this SO question: [Form post asp classic xmlhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452505/form-post-asp-classic-xmlhttp) or this Microsoft support article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290591 using ServerXMLHttp from MSXML but I've not tried that method myself so it's just an alternative suggestion to using the DLL.

Your form data that you'd 'Send' in the ServerXMLHttp case would be a form encoded list of the variables like
`username=YOURUSERNAME&password=YOURPASSWORD&account=EX000000&recipient=44770000000&body=hello`

Feel free to give further examples of how you want to call the Esendex API from your code if it'll help and you can get excellent support from Esendex by emailing support@esendex.com.